# Regarding greatest common divisors and primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If (a,b)=1, show that (a+b,(a^p+b^p)/(a+b))=1 or p, where p is an odd prime.

I am just a beginner of number theory, are there any hints of solving this problem?

Comment: You'd need to provide some details as to your comfort level with working with GCD, etc. EG Do you know how to use the remainder factor theorem in a situation like this?